# how can i implement a split button like below given image

Tags: android

i want this kind of drop-down button on my layout. i don't know the exact term, Please Help

[image]

I don't want a list, i only want when somebody tries to know about topic then he may click on that button, then button get split and all description related to specific topic will be shown to person.
I don't know how it would be implemented so i request the professionals to post answers
I searched from too many resources and tried to implement but i couldn't implement

Thank you

Comment: where is *given image*

Comment: @Ravi It's in the tiny link in the "1".  Not easy to see.

Comment: Click on [1] to see picture, i'm really sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is known as `ExpandableListView`. Refer to [this example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The closest component in Swing would be a `JTree`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more information and working examples.

The next closest would be a `JList`, but you would need to add all the logic to support the expanding/collapsing of the list.

Comment: camickr thank you so much, i found the correct tutorial with your support. Thank you :)

Comment: Oops, just noticed this is an Android question. Not sure if the answer is relevant.